# React Redux keeps returning multiple reducer objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to render just one object property but it ends up renderings all other objects undefined aside from the targeted property. I'm fairly new to Redux, reducers, etc so any help would be great!

```
// Letters reducer 
export default function() {
return [
    {
      x: {
        start: 10,
        finish: 100
      }
    },
    {
      y: {
        start: 20,
        finish: 100
      }
    },
    {
      z: {
        start: 30,
        finish: 100
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

The component

```
renderList() {
  this.props.letters.map(i => {
    console.log(i.x.start);
  });
}
```

the console out is

```
{current: 10, goal: 100}
2 undefined  < -- my Y and Z, which idk why it's getting called.
```

but if I try calling it like this it works

```
console.log(this.props.letters[0].x.start)
// 10
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't `console.log`ing `i.x`, not `i.x.start`?

Comment: *"which idk why it's getting called."* Your array has three elements, so the callback you pass to `.map` is called three times. However, only the first object has an `x` property. Accessing `x` on the other two objects will return `undefined`. This has nothing to do with redux or reducers specifically, it's how JavaScript works. Maybe you want to have a single object with `x`, `y` and `z` properties instead?

Comment: @FelixKling ahh I had a hypothesis that a single object with x,y,z properties might be a solution. But thanks for breaking it down for me.

Comment: @FelixKling I actually just tried it, and it worked. In my head I thought the entire reducer was a single object, which was why I was wrote the map function like that.